# Angular sass not generating css files

Tags: angular, sass

I'm working on an angular (version 5.2.10) template which is a tad outdated.

When perform an ng serve I'm getting the following **errors** for the css files in the browser console.

> Refused to apply style from
>   'http://localhost:4200/vendor/styles/bootstrap.bundle.css' because its
>   MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and
>   strict MIME checking is enabled.

Here is the error found inside the **ng serve log**

> Including .css files with @import is non-standard behaviour which will
>   be removed in future versions of LibSass. Use a custom importer to
>   maintain this behaviour. Check your implementations documentation on
>   how to create a custom importer.

I see this relates to a [breaking change](https://github.com/sass/libsass/releases) made to the **sass dependency**, but I'm not quite sure what to do about it.

My version of node sass is "4.9.0".

and style sheet link look like this in the index.html

```
<!-- Core stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/styles/bootstrap.bundle.css" class="theme-settings-bootstrap-css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/styles/appwork.bundle.css" class="theme-settings-appwork-css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/styles/theme-corporate.bundle.css" class="theme-settings-theme-css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/styles/colors.bundle.css" class="theme-settings-colors-css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/styles/uikit.bundle.css">
```

Comment: Why did you add the css file to html instand of the  angular,json file ??

Comment: can you shae the style.scss , I belive the error related to this file not index.html